# How does one draw to a dynamically created button control?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code I have:

```
Button b = new Button();
Graphics g = b.CreateGraphics();

g.DrawString("Hello World", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 5), Brushes.Red, new PointF(1, 1));

b.Height = 100;
b.Width = 100;

this.Controls.Add(b);
```

I get a button but no image on it..

I am using the following code, which does what I need. Thanks everyone.

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Height = 100;
b.Width = 100;

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(b.Height, b.Width);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
g.DrawString("Hello World", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 5), Brushes.Red, new PointF(1, 1));

b.Image = bitmap;
this.Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: Why not use `b.Text` to set the text of the button instead of using graphics objects?

Comment: @MatthewRz that doesn't help at all.

Comment: @MatthewRz again that doesn't help. I don't want text. It's just a sample.

Comment: And what do you mean by no image on the button?

Comment: The DrawString method draws an image onto the graphics object. In this case the graphic is a string.

Comment: You'll need to use the button's Paint event.

Comment: Where do you add the graphic to the button?

Comment: @Bob I assume it's g.Drawstring since g is made from the button control.

Comment: @carny666 Have you tried setting Button Image property? i.e. b.Image = g From the MSND doc, I'm interpretting that the CreateGraphics() method only creates a local instance of it, and not actually bound to the button.

Comment: @carny666 Did you get an error? And if yes, what was it?

Comment: @Bob No error, sorry, I retracted what I said about the image and backgroundimage properties. They work fine for me. Do you know if I can use Graphics methods on the Image or Bitmap classes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Button Image property to set an image onto the button.

```
 Button b = new Button();
 Bitmap picture = new Bitmap();
 b.Image = picture;
```